# How does one convert "flowJO" flow-cytometry cell-count, etc, bead, etc data into .json or relational-database-management-system compatible files?

Tags: database, software-recommendation, format-conversion, flow-cytometry

How does one convert "flowJO" flow-cytometry cell-count data into ".json" or relational-database-management-system compatible files?

The way flow-jo exports is in wide rather than long format. It also exports everything per subject/animal/lab-rat per specific timepoints rather than aggregating. I need the aggregated files to plot groups.

It's also not shaped in a "primary-key", column 1, column 2, column 3, or .json (NO_SQL) format.
Running statistical programs or databases is intractable with the export options Flowjo gives.

I am looking for some way to convert it, or maybe the problem lies in flowjo. It does not support the export formats I need.
I amk open to other flow-cytometry software that offers better integration with no-sql/sql database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.